# Reading data from Xml using XDocument C#

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0

I am trying to read data from XML in c# but i don't know how to get data of isActive node from following xml

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<email isActive="true">
</email>
```

I need to get the value of isActive

**Code:**

```
string peopleXMLPath = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "Config.xml");
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(peopleXMLPath);
```

Comment: Is `email` the root element, or a descendant?

Comment: yeah its root element

Answer (score 0):

you can use mentioned code

```
var xml = XElement.Load (@"c:\directory\Data_Config.xml");
var query = from e in xml.Descendants("email") select e.Attribute("isActive").Value;
```

if you have root node then you can use below mentioned code

```
Document xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\directory\Data_Config.xml");
var attrib = xdoc.Root.Attribute("isActive").Value;
```